# inequality for integral of Riemann

Tags: real-analysis, integration

let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ increasing and continuous. Show that, if $x\in (a,b)$, then 
$$\frac{1}{x-a}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\leq \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt\leq \frac{1}{b-x}\int_{x}^{b}f(t)dt.$$

I know that the function $\frac{1}{x-a}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ is bounded, if $f$ is bounded, but i do not have an idea to prove the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first inequality
$$
\frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \leq \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$
For this, it would be enough to show that the map
$$
x \mapsto \frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
is increasing on $(a,b)$. Indeed, differentiation with respect to $x$ shows that this function has derivative given by
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{(x-a)^2}\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t + \frac{f(x)}{x-a}.
\end{align*}
This is non-negative on $(a,b)$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x)}{x-a} \geq \frac{1}{(x-a)^2}\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \iff
f(x) \geq \frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
for all $a < x < b$. But this is true because, by monotonicity,
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x f(x)\,\mathrm{d}t \geq \frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$
The second inequality can be proven similarly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $g : (a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{x-a} \int_a^x f(t) \mathrm{dt}$$

$g$ is differentiable and
$$g'(x)= \frac{-1}{(x-a)^2} \int_a^x f(t) \mathrm{dt} + \frac{1}{x-a}f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a} \left( f(x) - \frac{1}{x-a} \int_a^x f(t) \mathrm{dt} \right)$$

Now because $f$ is increasing, $f(t) \leq f(x)$ for all $t \in [a,x]$. Therefore,
$$ \int_a^x f(t) \mathrm{dt} \leq  \int_a^x f(x) \mathrm{dt} = f(x)(x-a)$$

You deduce that 
$$g'(x) \geq \frac{1}{x-a} \left( f(x) - \frac{x-a}{x-a} f(x)\right) = 0$$

i.e. $g$ is increasing.

In particular, for all $x$, $g(x) \leq g(b)$, which is the left part of your inequality.

You can prove the right part the same way.